# See if lat / long falls within a polygon using mysql, there is any function now?

Tags: geolocation, polygon

I´m trying to know if '5.03529 -754368' is within the polygon, can you help me, how can I do that?

I see that the two fields have different formats, how can I fix this?

select within ('5.03529 -754368',PyPolygon) from manuelitapolygon

PyPolygon = 'POLYGON((5.035247876391217 -75.43594128570524,5.035158505114919 -75.43594598760016,5.03507011299693 -75.43596004176999,5.034983668480416 -75.43598329423428,5.0349001186705165 -75.43601549023417,5.034820378957751 -75.43605627702355,5.034745322988647 -75.436105207733864))'

Answer (score -1):

See [Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias, señor Joey, Ahora Tengo Este   select PyNombre,contains (PyPolygon, GeomFromText('Point(8.30941
-73.6010)')) from manuelitapolygon      but if I have lat and long, how can I do that 'point(lat long)' don't work